# How do I find out when I will be able to change country in play store again?

Tags: google-play-store

I know I can only change once per year, I but I don't remember when I last changed it. I think it was close to a year ago, but I would like to be able to see what date the 1 year will expire so I can set a reminder then to go and change my country.

p.s. why is this once per year restriction in place? is it a legal thing or a commercial thing? Does not make sense to me.

Comment: Good question and I couldn't find an answer. Maybe Google intimated to you by mail after you changed. Did you check your profile using web browser - maybe it's mentioned there. Easiest thing would be from Play Store settings go to help and feedback and mail them. Regarding your PS-we can't answer that, we aren't Google

Comment: I would assume that the country change restriction exists to allow regional offers. If anybody could simply switch the country at any time to get a certain regional offer such offers would not make much sense anymore. Hence I would assume the reason if commercial. Of course this also simplifies the tax calculations per user (and enhances the chance that the taxes are collected for the correct country).